# Call methods in C# asynchronously

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have 6 service hits in a page which are called in Dashboard page load event
In these methods I have to bind ASP chart methods.
By performance wise the page is loading slow. Here I don't have another option to get all the details in one method
So how can I bind asynchronous for these methods? 
Thanks in advance
Here is my code

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                BindTransactionCountDetails();
                BindTransactionAmountDetails();
                BindCustomerInfo();
                BindBalanceInfo();
                BindTasCount();
                BindTagReadersCount();
        }
```

Calling these methods one by one, so time is taking to load the page. So I want to call above methods asynchronously.

Comment: This question is very poorly formulated, and it's hard to understand what you're trying to accomplish. Consider rewriting it, and try describing in more detail exactly what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Do any of the methods depend on the result of any of the others, or are they entirely independent?

Comment: All are Independent methods

Comment: Try looking at this: [Understanding a Simple Async Program](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2012/06/26/understanding-a-simple-async-program.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try (this requires .NET 4 or newer):

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(BindTransactionCountDetails));
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(BindTransactionAmountDetails));
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(BindCustomerInfo));
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(BindBalanceInfo));
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(BindTasCount));
tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(BindTagReadersCount));

Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```